# OffsetTime in NodaTime

Tags: c#, .net, nodatime

I'm looking for some kind of `OffsetTime` support in NodaTime, but am not seeing anything. I am receiving data in a format such as "17:13:00+10:00". I am to treat this as a time offset, applying it to a given date (which the user is in control of) to arrive at a local time for display purposes.

The best I've been able to come up with is this:

```
// the date for this OffsetDateTime will be 1/1/2000
var parsed = OffsetDateTimePattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("HH:mm:sso<G>").Parse(input).Value;

var desiredLocalDate = new LocalDate(2017, 06, 13);
var adjusted = new OffsetDateTime(
    new LocalDateTime(desiredLocalDate.Year, desiredLocalDate.Month, desiredLocalDate.Day, parsed.Hour, parsed.Minute, parsed.Second, parsed.Millisecond),
    parsed.Offset);
var localTime = adjusted.LocalDateTime;
```

I guess I'm wondering whether I'm overlooking a better way to do this.

Comment: [DateTimeZone](http://nodatime.org/unstable/api/NodaTime.DateTimeZone.html)?

Comment: I'm confused by "applying it to a given date (which the user is in control of)". This mean the user is in control of the date, but has no knowledge that an offset will be applied? Is the user instructed to enter the date in effect in the time zone the user's computer is set to? Is the user entering the date in effect as the user is typing, or could it be an older date, when the time zone rules could have been different?

Comment: It makes a big difference whether the date is today's date and your program is processing it immediately, or if it is an old date. To figure out the local date for an old date you need to know the name of the time zone, not just the offset, to account for daylight saving time and legislative changes to time zones.

Comment: @GerardAshton understood, but I have no control over the data being provided to me. So using lenient conversions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: this will now be in Noda Time 2.3.

---

No, there isn't anything representing this in Noda Time. It's a pretty odd kind of value, as in at least many time zones, the offset will vary over the year. I understand that sometimes we need to work with what we've got though.

I'd probably keep it as two fields: an `Offset`, and a `LocalTime`. You can then build an `OffsetDateTime` once you have a `LocalDate`. You could obtain those two via an `OffsetDateTime` as you're doing already, but I'd suggest splitting it into the two values as soon as possible, to avoid any hint that there's a useful date in there.

If you want to keep your existing code structure, you can at least make it much simpler:

```
// The date for this OffsetDateTime will be 1/1/2000
// Note: the pattern can be created once and reused; it's thread-safe.
var parsed = OffsetDateTimePattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("HH:mm:sso<G>")
    .Parse(input).Value;
var desiredLocalDate = new LocalDate(2017, 06, 13);
var adjusted = desiredLocalDate.At(parsed.TimeOfDay).WithOffset(parsed.Offset);
var localTime = adjusted.LocalDateTime;
```

Note that `localTime` here will always be equivalent to `desiredLocalDate.At(parsed.TimeOfDay)` - it's not like the offset is "added" to it.

Comment: Thanks Jon. Actually, that last point you make about the offset not being taken into account when requesting `LocalDateTime` is on my list as something to chase down. How do I calculate the correct local time for a given `OffsetDateTime`? Happy to open another Q if necessary.

Comment: @KentBoogaart: An `OffsetDateTime` already represents a `LocalDateTime` at a particular offset - "17:13:00+10:00" means "A local time of 17:13, it's 07:13 UTC". You can use `OffsetDateTime.WithOffset` to change the offset while retaining the same `LocalDateTime`, e.g. to get the "local time in UTC" as it were, you could use `WithOffset(Offset.Zero).LocalDateTime`.

Comment: Ah, yes. I worded that super poorly and confused myself in the process. Server is giving me e.g. "2017-01-01T13:30:00+10:30" and I need to figure out what that is in local time, which may be a different offset. So using your suggestion, I will `WithOffset` that, passing in the system clock's UTC offset. Thanks Jon!

Comment: @KentBoogaart: You shouldn't use the system clock's *current* UTC offset - it might not have been the same at that time. Call `ToInstant().InZone(zone)` with the time zone you're interested in, to find out what the local time would have been at that instant in time.

Comment: Kent Boogaart wrote 'Server is giving me e.g. "2017-01-01T13:30:00+10:30" and I need to figure out what that is in local time, which may be a different offset.' The string passed already contains somebody's local time,  "2017-01-01T13:30:00+10:30" which is 03:30:00 UTC. So you need to establish exactly what different local time you want, and whether you want to express it as an OffsetDateTime (which contains an offset but not a full-fledged time zone) or a ZonedDateTime (which has full-fledged time zone information).

Comment: Great point, Jon. I have implemented this per your advice and all is working. Thanks again.

Comment: @KentBoogaart: We're now implementing this in Noda Time 2.3, btw.